# @elastic/elasticsearch-mock Cannot destructure property `ConfigurationError` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, elasticsearch, lambda

I am trying to mock `@elastic/elasticsearch` using the lib `@elastic/elasticsearch-mock`.

I have used the code as per the document and tried running but getting this

Code

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
const Mock = require('@elastic/elasticsearch-mock');

const mock = new Mock();
const client = new Client({
            node: 'http://localhost:9200',
            Connection: mock.getConnection()
 });
client.info(console.log)
```

But getting this error,

```
/home/app/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch-mock/index.js:18
  ConfigurationError,
  ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property `ConfigurationError` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch-mock/index.js:17:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.hookedLoader [as _load] (/home/app/node_modules/mockery/mockery.js:111:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/test/lib/es-helper-test.js:12:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.hookedLoader [as _load] (/home/app/node_modules/mockery/mockery.js:111:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at /home/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:220:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/home/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:217:14)
    at Mocha.run (/home/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:485:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:403:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/client-testing.html

Lib issue link : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js-mock/issues/15

Versions

```
 "@elastic/elasticsearch": "7.13.0"
"@elastic/elasticsearch-mock": "^0.3.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a resolver even just to console log the client.

From the very limited [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/elasticsearch-mock#usage).

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const Mock = require('@elastic/elasticsearch-mock')
 
const mock = new Mock()
const client = new Client({
  node: 'http://localhost:9200',
  Connection: mock.getConnection()
})
 
// Add this resolver 
mock.add({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/'
}, () => {
  return { status: 'ok' }
})
 
client.info(console.log)
```

From my understanding you will need to add every index, query, resolver, etc that you want to mock on the client since there is no database to query against - meaning you provide the data and tell the mock how you want it returned (also still learning this and the documentation for the mock library is quite brief)

Comment: I have already tested as per the document, but still, it's not working for me.

Comment: Elastic search (the java program) itself also needs to be installed on your local system for it to function properly (if it's not already). I'm also not sure what you mean by "tested"; did you try the added resolver?